# My SQL in XAMMP error in a database. Cannot delete a user in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I added some users to my database. when i click on the browse option. i can see my users but cannot delete them.

[image: Screenshot]

This is what i want to see, but cant see these options

[MySQL options i want to see, but cant find them. Click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq2dq.jpg)

Comment: Does your user have the correct access rights?

Comment: like what rights?

Comment: If you are not logged in as root, the users needs the correct permissions on the database.

Comment: the reason why you don't see some features in that table in phpMyAdmin is because none of your columns hae been defined as primary key. So all the features you highlight are not available. you can always do it with a simple query using one of the other columns as index. Ie `DELETE FROM table WHERE first_name='name-to-be-deleted`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if you are a root user by following below steps:

1. Go to home in phpmyadmin panel by clicking on home icon on top-left corner.
2. There on your right side a box named "Database server" will show the information.
   [image: User information in phpmyadmin panel]

Also check the privileges(rights) for the specific table; go to the table where you are trying to delete users and in top you will see a privileges tab go there and check which privileges(rights) do you have.

Comment: i checked and the user is root@localhost

Comment: Did you checked privileges of that specific table? Check that process are mentioned after image. ;)

Comment: I have tried and reinstalled XAMMP. I made a new user and granted him all access. But still no luck to see the delete option when the new user is added.

Comment: Are you adding users by scripts or by graphical way? Which ever method you are using must have issue there; tell me the steps by which you are creating table and users. I will try to solve your problem.